# Where do I download an older version of Safari for Windows

Tags: windows, download, compatibility, version

I need a specific version of Safari using WebKit 525.27; I have tracked it to Safari 3.2.1. The first Google hit on Apple points to:

> http://support.apple.com/downloads/Safari_3_2_1_for_Windows?viewlocale=sv_SE

However all the download links direct me to Safari 5. Are my only options to either build it myself from webkit.org or download it from an Internet archive like [oldapps](http://www.oldapps.com/apple_safari.php?old_safari=10)?

Comment: Any particular reason you need this specific version? Is it behavior or e.g. just the user agent string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get it here

http://www.oldapps.com/apple_safari.php

Comment: Ok, but its crap that the Apple download site is broken... But who cares, why should Apple keep a legacy archive of the past...

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered, but I like to give people options. Another option is filehippo.com. They have every version of a lot of programs out there including popular items such as Safari. [Here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_safari/) is the link that would be relevant to this question. Below are some of the other very popular downloads that Filehippo has.

- Firefox
- CCleaner
- Flash Player
- VLC Media Player
- MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

That's bad luck.

The links for multiple versions of Safari are here.

http://support.apple.com/downloads/#internet

However, the active links for the Windows versions only work back to 3.2.2.

The Mac versions appear to go back to 1.3.1.

This is the page for 3.2.1.
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL721
Unfortunately, the DL link now points to the current release.